# Disable the automatic rejection of questions without matching tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, migration

Migrations can be automatically rejected, the two major reasons this happens are

- the user is question banned on the target site
- the question does not havy *any* tag that exists on the target site

The first check makes a lot of sense, but I can't see why we would actually want to do the second one. Tagging varies a lot between sites, and it is easily possible to create false positives for this check, questions that would be appropriate for the target site but don't have any tags that match it. One example where this happens is between Math Overflow and Math SE because MO uses arXiv classification as a base for their tags, so they often don't match the MSE tags.

I'm not convinced the check does much good, and there is already a major system that is meant to reduce the number of migrations to completely wrong sites. The community can only migrate to sites on a short list, and those sites are selected carefully and removed if too many bad migrations happen. I think this is sufficient for most cases, and I can't imagine this tag check to prevent any significant volume of bad migrations. For such a question I find the chance for false positivies not worth it.

Another issue is that the rejection is entirely silent, which can easily confuse users.

Comment: Same problem with Excel (SO) and Microsoft-Excel (SU).